# getLastId does not bring the last id in a foreach

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am getting the IDs generated from each insert and adding to another table that I created, but the last id is not registered, for example: select a category that should insert 6 data, but in the table created by me and with the code below only registers 5 , and the data is entered all in the other table that already comes in Opencart.

**My Model**

```php
public function setDiscount($productId, $price, $di, $df, $subTotal2 = 0, $percent, $category, $store, $identifier) {
        $subTotal2 = ($price * ($this->request->post['dietpro_discount_amount'])) / 100;
        $price -= $subTotal2;
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special (product_id,customer_group_id,priority,price,date_start,date_end) VALUES ('$productId','1','1','$price','$di','$df'),('$productId','2','1','$price','$di','$df')");

        $productSpecialId = $this->db->getLastId();

        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special_discounts (product_special_id, percent, category, store, identifier, date_start, date_end) VALUES ('$productSpecialId', '$percent', '$category', '$store', '$identifier', '$di', '$df')");

}
```

**My Controller**

```php
$date = new DateTime();
$identifier = $date->getTimestamp();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $di = $this->request->post['dietpro_discount_date_start'];
    $df = $this->request->post['dietpro_discount_date_end'];

    $percent = $this->request->post['dietpro_discount_amount'];
    $store = $product['name'];
    $productId = $product['product_id'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $category = $product['model'];

    $this->model_total_dietpro_discount->setDiscount($productId, $price, $di, $df, $subTotal2, $productId, $percent, $category, $store, $identifier);
}
```

Comment: not familiar with opencart but, in **My Controller** you are passing an `$identifier` param which does not appear to be initialized anywhere there. Also, you are passing `$productID` as both the first and sixth param. maybe check those out

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The $Identifier is a timestamp to store a unique ID of all inserts so I can delete all of them by calling $identifier.
About duplicity, I really had not noticed. thank you.

Comment: Correct, but still not get the last id.

Comment: let me c if I understood, you are traversing `$products`, which should have 6 elements, right?, and inserting into two tables *product_special* and *product_special_discount*, but the problem is you only see 5 products inserted in each table, is that the problem? well, have you checked the size of `$products`? you can do that by putting this before the `foreach`: `var_dump(count($products));die();`. see how many elements `$products` actually has

Comment: Almost this has an array with products, and in the example I mentioned 6, which is the actual quantity of products of a sub store, but idependently gives quantity of products added, always the last one is not added to the table that I created, which is ```product_special_discounts``` . There is another table called ```product_special```, in which all data is added.

Comment: that's ok but, the idea of `var_dump(count($products));die();` before the `foreach` is just to check possible issues out, like `$products` not containing all the items you think it contains. That way if you try to insert N rows, but you see that `$products` only has, for example, N-1 items, then you know the problem is somewhere around the process of populating `$products`, not  inside the `foreach` nor inside `setDiscount`.

Comment: Returns all three records.
There is a detail, the insert inserts twice, a record for physical and legal persons, ```INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special (product_id,customer_group_id,priority,price,date_start,date_end) VALUES ('$productId','1','1','$price','$di','$df'),('$productId','2','1','$price','$di','$df')```

Comment: In total I should have six, two for each insert. example: product A, product B and product C, product A is registered for physical person and legal person, then A1 and A2, understand? In total they should have six, but only the last one makes an insert, in the tab I created, but in the native table of the system inserts all.